# How to refetch a scope value in view using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all sorry if my title doesn't quite explain my problem. I have a form which is create a set of question dynamically. In the code below I use ng-repeat="opt in q.options" and I have a button which add a new option.

My view code

```
<div>
<label for="">Options: </label>
<a ng-click="addOption($event, $index)">
    <i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add option
</a><br /><br />
<div ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
    <label><span>{{opt.id}}.</span></label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="opt.text" placeholder="Add new possible answer here.">
    <a ng-click="q.options.splice($index,1)"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<label for="required_credit">Answer: </label>
    <select id="city" ng-options="c for c in options">
    </select>
<!-- <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="opt in q.options">{{opt.id}}</li>
</ul> -->
```

What I want is to reuse q.options in my select tags but it the problem is it doesn't populate. I've used ul li tags then ng-repeat="q.options" and it worked but I want to use it using the select tags.

PS: The reason why I want to use the same model is to simply get the appended data which I inserted dynamically.

For instance:

1. I have 2 input buttons and I add a new input button
2. Since I'm using the same model my select option would then be updated then it would have 3 options as well.

Comment: How about `ng-options="c for c in q.options"`. Also you 're missing `ng-model` on the select.

Comment: hi CodeHater, it worked when I added a ng-model in my select tags. This is odd, without the ng-model I wasn;t able to populate the data. Is this the correct behaviour?

Comment: Basically using `ng-options` you specify the values the options would hold and `ng-model` keeps data-binding happy. Probably that's why it asks for both.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly the [ngSelect documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), ng-model is a required parameter for ngSelect. I believe, you want to store your selected value somewhere ;)